# How to dynamically update prices for menu website?

Tags: javascript, django, content-management-system, hosting, web-hosting

I would like to publish a website that hosts menus for different restaurant branches.
What would be good way to do publish this?
Bearing in mind occasional price changes - does this mean taking the website down and re-deploying or is there a way I can dynamically update item prices?

Hosting providers/CMS tools appreciated

I have written the website using basic html/css/js so far.. I have only used django to host a website on the local loopback address. I am determined to learn more.

Comment: Try your luck at [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Hi, Django is a great way to manage the functionality of such a site. To answer your specific question, you can access the ‘admin’ portal and update prices while the site is running. This is immediately updated on the frontend of the site.
I suggest following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/) to learn all the elements you will need. Good luck with your website!

Answer (score 1):

The first question would be can you access the price data online? (Other websites?)

If you are able, to get the data online then you could create a database and small program which fetches the required data for the website. You can then give that a refreshing rate of 5 min or what ever you like.

Then give your website to access the database and load the prices/data from the database into your website.

If you do not have the data online you can still use a database for storing the prices and other data. If you store the data in database you can load it from the database into your website.

To update the data you can either insert the values directly into the database or you can write an webinterface. (Do not forget to restrict the access to the webinterface)

For the communication I would recommend to use CRUD methods ( Create Read Update Delete) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete